# createElement styling

Tags: javascript, dom, createelement

I'm beginner in DOM javascript, So I have such a question.
I have html form like that =>

```
<div id="name_field" style="text-align: center;">
    <form name="add" action="index.php" method="post">
    Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="name_" id="name_" size="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="some" onclick="addChild();">Add&nbsp;More</a><br>
    <span id="a">here is that</span>
    </form>
</div>
```

And want to call like it is seen addChild() function which will append "input" element in div with style (css) content. I have such a javascript code =>

```
function addChild()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("name_field");
    var el = document.createElement("input");
    el.style.size = 10;
    div.appendChild(el);
}
```

But it is not working ... Also need to append "input" element from above to below and how to do that , if anyone help me. Thanks ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `size` of an `input` element isn't a style property. It's a property of the `input` element itself.

So this...

```
el.style.size = 10;
```

should be this...

```
el.size = 10;
```

---

I just don't know what you mean by *"Also need to append "input" element from above to below..."*.

Comment: You're right, but it's probably 'better' (for site-consistency) to use the CSS approach: `el.style.width = '10em';` (for example). Though, equally obviously, it's not what the OP asked...regardless, +1

Comment: Also Have another I think easy question , I'm trying to add added field input field attributes like "name" equal to something and how to do that ? :)

Comment: @Tornike: You'd just assign the name to the `el.name` property.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Valid point. Using `.size` feels very yesterday.

Comment: This everything clear and works but how it can be written to append fields below each other ? :)

Comment: @Tornike: Create a `br` and append that as well. `var br = document.createElement('br'); div.appendChild(br);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no style.size. Maybe you are looking for style.height or style.width?

Comment: I want to change size on input form (field) , how to do that ?

Comment: I'd suggest using the latter `el.style.width = '10em';` (for example), because the `size` attribute reflects the character-width (IIRC) of the `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is no size in the style. u can set height and width.

ele.style.width ='10px';

But after it also it is not cross browser competible so u can go with,

ele.setAttribute('style','width:10px;height:10px');

The size which you using will be vary in Firefox and IE. !!!